# TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function C# y Full Calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

Estoy tratando de ejecutar en mi proyecto un calendario de eventos en bootstrap 4, solo que al momento de ejecutar mi JavaScript me arroga el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function

En donde mi codigo JavaScript es el siguiente:

```js
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Assets/css/CDOCalendar.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {      
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery('.datetimepicker').datepicker({ //error
            timepicker: true,
            language: 'en',
            range: true,
            multipleDates: true,
            multipleDatesSeparator: " - "
        });
        jQuery("#add-event").submit(function () {
            alert("Submitted");
            var values = {};
            $.each($('#add-event').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
                values[field.name] = field.value;
            });
            console.log(
                values
            );
        });
    });

    (function () {
        'use strict';
        // ------------------------------------------------------- //
        // Calendar
        // ------------------------------------------------------ //
        jQuery(function () {
            // page is ready
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
                // emphasizes business hours
                businessHours: false,
                defaultView: 'month',
                // event dragging & resizing
                editable: true,
                // header
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                },
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'Barber',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu pellentesque nibh. In nisl nulla, convallis ac nulla eget, pellentesque pellentesque magna.',
                        start: '2019-07-07',
                        end: '2019-07-07',
                        className: 'fc-bg-default',
                        icon: "circle"
                    },
                    
                ],
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    if (event.icon) {
                        element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-" + event.icon + "'></i>");
                    }
                },
                dayClick: function () {
                    jQuery('#modal-view-event-add').modal();
                },
                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                    jQuery('.event-icon').html("<i class='fa fa-" + event.icon + "'></i>");
                    jQuery('.event-title').html(event.title);
                    jQuery('.event-body').html(event.description);
                    jQuery('.eventUrl').attr('href', event.url);
                    jQuery('#modal-view-event').modal();
                },
            })
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

y mi código HTML es el siguiente

```html
<div class="p-5">
    <h2 class="mb-4">Calendario CDO</h2>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body p-0">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- calendar modal -->
<div id="modal-view-event" class="modal modal-top fade calendar-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="event-icon"></span><span class="event-title"></span></h4>
                <div class="event-body"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="modal-view-event-add" @*class="modal modal-top fade calendar-modal"*@>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="add-event">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Add Event Detail</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Event name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ename">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Event Date</label>
                        <input type='text' class="datetimepicker form-control" name="edate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Event Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="edesc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Event Color</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="ecolor">
                            <option value="fc-bg-default">fc-bg-default</option>
                            <option value="fc-bg-blue">fc-bg-blue</option>
                            <option value="fc-bg-lightgreen">fc-bg-lightgreen</option>
                            <option value="fc-bg-pinkred">fc-bg-pinkred</option>
                            <option value="fc-bg-deepskyblue">fc-bg-deepskyblue</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Event Icon</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="eicon">
                            <option value="circle">circle</option>
                            <option value="cog">cog</option>
                            <option value="group">group</option>
                            <option value="suitcase">suitcase</option>
                            <option value="calendar">calendar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En donde quiero mostrar un modal en donde pueda agregar el evento en el día que yo seleccione, pero al ejecutar el código me arroga el error
No se en donde estará el problema
Estaré al pendiente si requieren mayor información

Comment: Hola, donde llamas a los scripts y css de Bootstrapp 4?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder utilizar a funcionalidad `datepicker` de Bootstrap 4, necesitas hacer referencia al **plugin** **bootstrap-datepicker** en tu código HTML.

Para el archivo de clases css:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Y para el archivo JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Por supuesto, debes tener también referenciadas las librerías y css de **jQuery** y **Bootstrap4** generales.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Tu solución a resuelto mi problema!!